# ¿Cómo modifico varios valores de un objeto en react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, usestate

estoy usando React con Typescript y quisiera poder cambiar varios campos de un objeto, uso el *hook* **useState**.

El objeto tiene una interfaz así:

```
interface iu {
   nombre: string;
   num_seguidores: number;
   siguiendo: boolean;
}
```

El **useState** esta definido así:

```
const [user, setUser] = React.useState<iu>({
   nombre: "Luis",
   num_seguidores: 0,
   siguiendo: false
}):
```

Tambien cree un método para poder cambiar el estado **user** así:

```
const cambiarUser = (_campo: string, _valor: any) => {
   setUser({
      ...user,
      [_campo]: _valor
   });
}
```

Entonces en cualquier parte del código, al llamar a **cambiarUser** si funciona, ejemplo:

```
cambiarUser("nombre", "Luiss");
```

Mi problema es cuando quiero cambiar dos campos a la vez, por ejemplo, *num_seguidores* y *siguiendo*:

```
cambiarUser("num_seguidores", user.num_seguidores + 1);
cambiarUser("siguiendo", true);
```

Solo me actualiza el ultimo campo, que seria **siguiendo**, pero **num_seguidores** no cambia .

Comment: Actualicé la respuesta, agregando el tema de `funcional updates`. saludos

Comment: .@DJLuis ¿Tienes Feedback, las respuestas son de utilidad? Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias @g.4 Me ayudaste muchísimo. Aunque no comprendo del todo la lógica cuando usaste **useReducer**

Comment: .@DJLuis se actualizó la respuesta explicando el procedimiento con useReducer, saludos

Answer (score 0):

Cuando se hace la llamada a `setUser` de esta forma:

```
const cambiarUser = (_campo: string, _valor: any) => {
       setUser({
          ...user,
          [_campo]: _valor
       });
}

function handler(){
    cambiarUser("num_seguidores", user.num_seguidores + 1);
}
```

ReactJS toma la última captura en `scope` para el estado `user`:

```
{
   nombre: "Luis",
   num_seguidores: 0,
   siguiendo: false
}
```

Se actualiza el estado para `num_seguidores` y reactJS devuelve el componente. Hasta aquí afirmamos nuestro conocimiento de la devolución de componentes, despues de actualizar un estado:

```
{nombre: "Luis", num_seguidores: 1, siguiendo: false}
```

---

#### La captura de user no ha cambiado, ReactJS aún no devuelve

Pero, cuando se hace la llamada a `setUser` en multiples ocaciones dentro del mismo scope `handler`, JS no espera a que el primer `cambiarUser->setUser`(operación asincrónica) regrese de la lista de tareas con el state `user` actualizado (nueva captura), para luego ejecutar el siguiente `cambiarUser->setUser`y así sucesivamente... **No**, JS continua su ejecución...

Mas detalles en los comentarios a continuación:

```
    function handler(){
        cambiarUser("num_seguidores", user.num_seguidores + 1);
        //ReactJS: cambiarUser scheduled asycn op in task queue
        //Current state in handler scope ->prevState 
        //{nombre: "Luis", num_seguidores: 0, siguiendo: false}
        //JS : aun no regreso, continuo
        cambiarUser("nombre", "Luiss");
        //ReactJS: cambiarUser scheduled asycn op in task queue
        //Current state in handler scope ->prevState 
        //{nombre: "Luis", num_seguidores: 0, siguiendo: false}
        //JS: aun no regreso continuo
        cambiarUser("siguiendo", true);
        //ReactJS: cambiarUser scheduled asycn op in task queue
        //Current state in handler scope ->prevState 
        //{nombre: "Luis", num_seguidores: 0, siguiendo: false}
        //JS: ya no hay nada, regresa funcion handler al call stack
        //ejecucion de async scheduled tasks
        //ReactJS: ejecuto cambiaUser para num_seguidores:1
        //prevState: captura actual en este scope
        //{nombre: "Luis", num_seguidores: 0, siguiendo: false}
        //newState
        //{nombre: "Luis", num_seguidores: 1, siguiendo: false}
        //ReactJS: ejecuto cambiaUser para nombre:Luiss
        //prevState: captura actual en este scope
        //{nombre: "Luis", num_seguidores: 0, siguiendo: false}
        //newState
        //{nombre: "Luiss", num_seguidores: 0, siguiendo: false}
        //ReactJS: ejecuto cambiaUser para siguiendo:true
        //prevState: captura actual en este scope
        //{nombre: "Luis", num_seguidores: 0, siguiendo: false}
        //newState
        //{nombre: "Luis", num_seguidores: 0, siguiendo: true}
        
    }
```

Nótese que hasta este punto, el estado `user` (`prevState`) no ha cambiado, **la captura de `user` sigue siendo la misma que al inicio de la `App` durante la ejecución de las operaciones asincrónicas `cambiaUser->setUser`, JS sigue en el mismo scope `handler` y ReactJS aún no devuelve** aquí:

```
    cambiarUser("siguiendo", true);
    //JS hanlder: esto es lo que tengo capturado en memoria para user, pues no he devuelto
    //user = {nombre: "Luis", num_seguidores: 0, siguiendo: false}
    //...
    const cambiarUser = (_campo: string, _valor: any) => {
        setUser({
            ...user,
           [_campo]: _valor //siguiendo: true
        });
    }
```

Por lo tanto, después de que ReactJS devuelve nuevamente el componente (re-render), como resultado se obtiene:

```
{nombre: "Luis", num_seguidores: 0, siguiendo: true}
```

---

#### Functional Updates

Una forma de hacer que este diseño, con propiedad computada ES6 funcione, es usando el hook `useState` en su version callback para [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates), el cual nos permite obtener la captura del estado previo, modificar y regresar su nuevo estado para llamadas consecutivas al setter `setState` que esten en el mismo scope, en este caso todas las llamadas a `cambiaUser` dentro de la funcion `handler`.

Para regresar el nuevo estado, dado que es un objeto, se usa el operador elipsis.

Dejo una demostración:

```js
function App(){
  const [state,setState] = React.useState({nombre: "Luis", num_seguidores: 0, siguiendo: false})
  
  
  const cambiarUser = (_campo, _valor) => {
    //version callback del setter de useState
    setState(prevState => {
      return {...prevState, [_campo]: _valor}
    })
  }
  
  function handler(){
    cambiarUser("num_seguidores", state.num_seguidores + 1);
    cambiarUser("nombre", "Luiss");
    cambiarUser("siguiendo", true);
    //JS: ya no hay nada, regresa funcion handler al call stack
    //ejecucion de async scheduled tasks
    //ReactJS: ejecuto cambiaUser para num_seguidores:1
    //prevState: captura actual en este scope
    //{nombre: "Luis", num_seguidores: 0, siguiendo: false}
    //newState
    //{nombre: "Luis", num_seguidores: 1, siguiendo: false}
    //ReactJS: ejecuto cambiaUser para nombre:Luiss
    //prevState: tomo el prevState del callback setState
    //{nombre: "Luis", num_seguidores: 1, siguiendo: false}
    //newState
    //{nombre: "Luiss", num_seguidores: 1, siguiendo: false}
    //ReactJS: ejecuto cambiaUser para siguiendo:true
    //prevState: tomo el prevState del callback setState
    //{nombre: "Luiss", num_seguidores: 1, siguiendo: false}
    //newState
    //{nombre: "Luiss", num_seguidores: 1, siguiendo: true}
  }
  console.log("state is", state)
  return <button onClick={handler}>Click me</button>
}


ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

---

#### Actualización

> Aunque no comprendo del todo la lógica cuando usaste useReducer

En la documentación de reactJS se recomienda usar el hook `useReducer` para casos de este típo.

El Hook `useReducer` puede configurarse de diferentes formas, el patrón mas común es usar una función `reducer`, la cual recibirá dos argumentos, el `state` (enviado implícitamente) y un objeto `action`.

Pero, para este caso de uso, en vez de `action` se va a pasar el cambio de estado, en su forma propiedad computada `[property]:value` como `newState`:

```
function reducer(state, newState){
  //...
}
```

Luego, como el cambio de estado `newState` es un objeto con una sola propiedad computada, se debe buscar la forma de obtener el nombre de la propiedad, para poder cambiar su nuevo valor en la estructura del objeto `state`.

Se propone el operador `elipsis`, para actualizar propiedades del objeto `state` durante una operación de propagación:

```
//la propagacion regresa el estado, mas un nuevo objeto
//simulando la propagacion
//{nombre: "Luis", num_seguidores: 0, siguiendo: false, {[property]:value}}
return {...state, newState}
```

En el ejemplo anterior, se esta regresando el objeto `state`, buscando que durante la iteración con el operador `elipsis`, `JS` vea la propiedad y cambie su valor; pero la propiedad computada se inserta como un objeto durante la iteración, mutando el objeto `state`. (función reducer impura)

Una solución a este problema, es propagar el objeto `newState`, que solamente tiene un parametro; de esta forma `JS` identifica el parametro durante la iteración y cambia su valor, regresando la estructura `state` original (función reducer pura):

```
//la propagacion regresa el estado y solo modifica
//el valor de la propiedad en newState
//simulando la propagacion
    //{nombre: "Luis", num_seguidores: 0, siguiendo: false, siguiendo: true}
//la propiedad siguiendo tiene un nuevo valor, se actualiza
//{nombre: "Luis", num_seguidores: 0, siguiendo: true}
    return {...state, ...newState}
```

Se propone esta función `reducer` con operador `elipsis`, porque en tu diseño original estas usando propiedades computadas ES6.

Dejo la demostración para que quede documentado:

```js
function reducer(state, newState){
  return {...state, ...newState};
}

const initState = {
  nombre: "Luis", 
  num_seguidores: 0, 
  siguiendo: false
}

function App(){
  const [state, setState] = React.useReducer(
    reducer,
    initState
  );
  
  const cambiarUser = (_campo, _valor) => {        
     setState({
       [_campo]: _valor
      })
  }
  
  function handler(){
    cambiarUser("num_seguidores", state.num_seguidores + 1);
    cambiarUser("nombre", "Luiss");
    cambiarUser("siguiendo", true);
  }
  console.log("state is", state)
  return <button onClick={handler}>Click me</button>
}


ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.