# Advertencia State dentro de useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

Tengo esta advertencia dentro de este useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setProyecto({
        ...proyecto,
        urlFirebase: urlImg
    })
}, [urlImg]);
```

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'proyecto'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. You can also do a functional update 'setProyecto(p => ...)' if you only need 'proyecto' in the 'setProyecto' call  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

intenté hacer lo que me aparece en la advertencia pero no me remplaza el valor que quiero, me elimina todo del state que es un objeto y me lo deja como un String con la url. Este es el useEffect que hice

```
useEffect(() => {
    setProyecto(p => p.urlFirebase = urlImg);
}, [urlImg]);
```

Comment: Intentaste agregando el proyecto a `[urlImg]`, más o menos quedaría de esta manera `[urlImg,proyecto]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> me elimina todo del state que es un objeto y me lo deja como un String con la url

Para poder modificar la estructura del objeto `state` de forma correcta, se tendría que usar el operador elípsis, propagar el objeto y posteriormente indicar la propiedad que va a cambiar su valor.

Por otro lado, [Functional Updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) se refiere al uso de la versión `callback` de `useState`, nos permite obtener la captura del estado previo, modificar y regresar su nuevo estado.

Puede que funcione de esta forma:

```
useEffect(() => {
    //version callback del setter de useState
    setProyecto(prevState => {
      return {...prevState, urlFirebase : urlImg}
    })
}, [urlImg]);
```

Saludos

[Functional Updates y propiedad computada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/443227/c%C3%B3mo-modifico-varios-valores-de-un-objeto-en-react/443267#443267)

Answer (score 0):

Para poder evitar la advertencia que se muestra dentro de las dependencias, debes agregar "proyecto" a tu arreglo que está al final de "useEffect", de la siguiente manera:

```
useEffect(() => {
setProyecto(p => p.urlFirebase = urlImg);
}, [urlImg, proyecto]);
```