# Como limitar el numero de respuestas a 6 de una api ( usando react y axios )?

Tags: reactjs, api, jsx, usestate

Estoy practicando `ReactJS` y quiero renderizar una lista de `superheroes`. En Javascript use un bucle `for` para que renderice hasta 6 templates con personajes de la `api` usando un `Id` en la `URL`, pero usando `JSX` no sé como hacerlo porque no reconoce la variable `heroe` en el `return`. Probe otras alternativas y no encontre solución aún.

```
import axios, * as others from 'axios';
import React, {useState} from "react";

const Equipo = () => {
  const [heroes, setHeroes] = useState(""); 
 
    axios.get(`https://superheroapi.com/api.php/token/${id}`, {
      "mode": "no-cors",
      "Headers": {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*",
      }
    })
    .then(response => {
      setHeroes(response)
  }) 
  .catch(e => {
    console.log(e)
  })
  
  return (
    <div style={{ alignItems: "center", textAlign: "center"}}>
    <h2 id="listaHeroes" style={{ fontSize:50}}>SuperHeroes</h2>
   { heroes.map( heroe => 
      <article>
      <h2>{heroe.name}</h2>
      <p>{heroe.appearance.gender}</p>
      
          <p>Inteligencia: {heroe.powerstats.intelligence}</p>
          <p>Fuerza: {heroe.powerstats.strength}</p>
          <p>Velocidad: {heroe.powerstats.speed}</p>
      
      <img src={heroe.image.url} alt="heroe" width="200px"/>
</article>
  ) }
    </div>
  );
  
}
export default Equipo;
```

Comment: Bienvenidx a la comunidad de Stackoverflow. Por favor lee o visita de nuevo  [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Recuerda que debes anteponer un título que describa bien el problema que tienes, así como resumir tu pregunta en los primeros párrafos, intentar pegar el código que haga replicar el problema o donde creas que esté el problema, etc. El formular una buena pregunta, aumentará tus posibilidades de recibir ayuda por parte de la comunidad.

Answer (score 2):

El código que nos compartes ya esta casi listo, solo faltan algunos detalles.

#### Manejo de Operaciones Asincrónicas useEffect

Un patrón común en ReactJS es usar el hook `useEffect` para operaciones asincrónicas, el **demo** muestra como se configura `useEffect` para correr solo una vez, cuando se monta el componente.

Aquí, se usa el clásico ciclo `for` para obtener los 6 heroes, usando el `index` como el parámetro `id` del `API endpoint`.

#### Functional Updates

Se usa [Functional Updates](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/462323/advertencia-state-dentro-de-useeffect/462658#462658) para obtener el último valor del estado `heroes` (previous state) y actualizar su nuevo estado; una vez que se obtiene el estado previo `heroes`, se propaga y se agrega el nuevo elemento.

#### JSX

Finalmente, se evalua cuando el arreglo `heroes` tiene una longitud de 6, solo entonces se devuelven los templates usando el arreglo `heroes`, tal cual lo tenias configurado, agregando además, la propiedad `key` en el tag `section`.

#### Demo

```
const Equipo = () => {
  const [heroes, setHeroes] = useState([]); 
  //Manejo de Operaciones Asincrónicas useEffect
  useEffect(()=>{
    for(let i = 1; i <= 6; i++){
      axios.get(`https://superheroapi.com/api.php/token/${i}`, {
        "mode": "no-cors",
        "Headers": {
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*",
        }})
        .then(response => {
          //functional update callback
          setHeroes(prevState => [...prevState, response.data]);
        }) 
        .catch(e => {
          console.log(e)
        });
    }
  },[]);

  //console.log(heroes);
  //JSX con operador ternario
  return (
    <div style={{ alignItems: "center", textAlign: "center"}}>
    <h2 id="listaHeroes" style={{ fontSize:50}}>SuperHeroes</h2>
      { (heroes.length === 6) ? heroes.map( heroe => 
          <article key={heroe.id}>
            <h2>{heroe.name}</h2>
            <p>{heroe.appearance.gender}</p>
            
                <p>Inteligencia: {heroe.powerstats.intelligence}</p>
                <p>Fuerza: {heroe.powerstats.strength}</p>
                <p>Velocidad: {heroe.powerstats.speed}</p>
            
            <img src={heroe.image.url} alt="heroe" width="200px"/>
          </article>
      ): <p>"Cargando datos..."</p> }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Nótese que antes de entrar a `useEffect`, se configura el estado `heroes` para ser un `array` en el hook `useState`.

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.

Comment: Estuve probando consultas a esa API y aún con las cabeceras sigue dando problemas de CORS. Recibo como response `access denied`. ¿Es posible que el error esté en el backend del cual viene la API? Lo digo por lo que encontré en está pregunta [Enable CORS from front-end in React with axios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55200786/enable-cors-from-front-end-in-react-with-axios)

Comment: Interesante @Desarrollos-Web-Urquiza, dime ¿Ya verificaste que tú número token este bien? Saludos

Comment: Si por "token" te refieres al número de `id`, probé con los mismos de tu ejemplo y recibo esa respuesta. Estuve revisando la documentación de esa API en [SuperHero API](https://superheroapi.com/index.html), pero no encuentro ejemplos con esa ruta exacta. Pienso que otra posibilidad es que la ruta de esa API sea incorrecta. Te paso el link del [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-spence-t5vk8?file=/src/App.js) en donde estoy haciendo las pruebas.

Comment: @Desarrollos-Web-Urquiza puede que te falte generar el [token de acceso/Getting your Access Token](https://superheroapi.com) es un número muy largo que se sustituye en donde dice `token` dentro de la `url`. Saludos

Comment: Ah, claro. Seguro debe ser ese el problema. Hay que loguearse con Facebook para generarlo.