# Problema con map dentro de map en React

Tags: javascript, array, reactjs, map, async-await

mi problema es el siguiente. Tengo una lista de usuarios y cada uno tiene una lista de propiedades, quisiera mostrarlos en una tabla en React, la lista de usuarios la recibo como un array de objetos, el problema es que la información de cada uno la debo obtener de manera asíncrona (también son un array de objetos) pero siempre recibo una promesa pendiente, este es el código:

```
const UsersTable = (props) => {
    const { users } = props;

    const getUserData = async (user_id) => {
        const userData = await axios
            .post("/user", { user_id })
            .then(({ data }) => data)
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
        return userData;
    };

    return (
        <>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>User</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {users
                        .slice(
                            currentPage * pageSize,
                            (currentPage + 1) * pageSize
                        )
                        .map((user) => {
                            const userData = getUserSteps(user.id).then((data)=> data);

                            console.log(userData); //Imprime una promesa pendiente

                            return (
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="row">{user.name}</th>
                                </tr>
                            );
                        })}
                </tbody>
            </table>
         </>
       );
  };
```

He intentado también colocando una función asíncrona dentro de la función map, pero me sigue devolviendo promesas:

```
{users
      .slice(
            currentPage * pageSize,
            (currentPage + 1) * pageSize
            )
      .map((user) => {
                      
                      const getData = async() => {

                          const data = await getUserData(user.id).then((data)=> data);
                          return await Promise.all(data)

                       }
                      console.log(getData()); //Imprime una promesa pendiente

                      return (
                              <tr>
                                  <th scope="row">{user.name}</th>
                              </tr>
      );
})}
```

La idea es poder obtener el Array de las propiedades de cada usuario para poder hacer otro pasarle la función map e imprimir el resto de las celdas de la tabla.

Muchas gracias.

EDIT: Estoy intentando con una función anónima asíncrona:

```
.map((user) => {
                            const userData = [];

                            (async () => {
                                const data = await getUserData(user.id);

                                data.map((data) => {
                                    userData.push(data);
                                });
                            })();

                            console.log(userData);
                            return (
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="row">{user.name}</th>
                                    {userData.map((data) => {
                                        return <td>{data}</td>;
                                    })}
                                </tr>
                            );
                        }
```

Los datos se van añadiendo al Array userData pero en el render no aparece, en consola sale un Array vacío que al desplegarlo muestra los datos, pero con la leyenda "this value was evaluated upon first expanding it may have changed since then".

Comment: Entonces ¿Cada objeto en `const { users } = props` solo contiene el `id` de cada usuario? ¿No tiene la propiedad `name`? saludos

Comment: Gracias por responder. Sí también tiene la propiedad `name` de hecho si solo renderizo la tabla con los nombres, todo sale perfecto, el problema es cuando quiero llamar las propiedades de cada usuario y pasarle a ese arreglo la función map() para retornar JSX con la información dentro de celdas, para ello uso la función `getUserData(user.id)`

Comment: ¿Y que hay con `currentPage` y `pageSize`? ¿vienen dentro de `users`?

Comment: No, esas constantes están porque estoy mostrando la tabla con paginación, para solo mostrar 10 usuarios a la vez.

Comment: Ya veo, entonces la llamada asincrónica que haces a `getUserData`, trae información por `user.id`, la cual no esta disponible en  `const { users } = props`, esa es la razón por la cual debes iterar el `map` 2 veces, ¿Puedes confirmar que esa es la situación?

Comment: Exacto, la información de `const { users } = props` la estoy recibiendo de una consulta a la BD de un componente padre, pero la tabla donde se hizo esa consulta no contiene la información detallada de cada usuario, solo id y nombre, entonces a partir del id de ese usuario obtengo el resto de la info de otra tabla (la cual hasta ahora recibo como promesa) y poderla iterar en otra función map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se puede modificar la lógica de iteración del método `render` en `UsersTable`, encapsulando esa operación asincrónica en un hook `useEffect` e iterando por cada `user` proveniente de `props.users`; además, se crea un nuevo estado `userArray` para ir colectando los nuevos datos provenientes de `getUserData` en forma de `array`:

```
  const { users } = props;
  const [userArray, setUserArray] = useState([]);
  useEffect(()=>{
    users.forEach(element => {
      getUserData(element.id).
        .then(response => {
          //functional update callback
          //aqui voy colectando los nuevos datos por user.id
          //lo propongo como response.data
          //verifica de tu lado como viene, 
          //debe ser un objeto con la info de user.id
          setUserArray(prevState => [...prevState, response.data]);
        }) 
        .catch(e => {
          console.log(e)
        });
    })
  },[users]);
```

En vez de hacer dos operaciones `map` en render time (dentro del return), se movió la lógica asincrónica dentro un `useEffect` con un `forEach`, ya que `props.users` es iterable.

Luego, se uso el setter `setUserArray` de `useState` para modificar los valores del estado para cada operación asincrónica y asegurar tener el último estado en cada nueva devolucion del componente `UsersTable`.

Ahora, al hacer esta modificación, se puede devolver la tabla usando solo el estado `userArray`, de la siguiente forma:

```
return (
    <>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>User</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {
              userArray.slice(
                currentPage * pageSize,
                (currentPage + 1) * pageSize
               ).map((user)=>(
                <tr key={user.i}>
                    <th scope="row">{user.name}</th>
                </tr>
              ))
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </>
  );
```

#### Notas de campo

- En la función setter `setUserArray` se usa [Functional Updates](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/462323/advertencia-state-dentro-de-useeffect/462658#462658) para obtener el último valor del estado `userArray` (previous state) y actualizar su nuevo estado; una vez que se obtiene el estado previo `userArray`, se propaga y se agrega el nuevo elemento.
- Con respecto a la páginación, faltaría que lo verifiques de tu lado.

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.

Comment: Muchas gracias, funcionó pasando la lógica al `useEffect()`, solo me falta acomodar un poco el orden del Array pero ya funciona como quería, gracias (:

Answer (score 0):

Existen varias cosas que débe tener en cuenta.

Si va a hacer operaciones asincronas, estás deben ser usadas mediante un efecto de react (mira [éste enlace](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)).

Tambié, podría mejorar la legibilidad de sus funciones asincronas evitando usar promesas adentro, así:

```
const URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";

const getData = async () => {
  try {
    const userData = await axios.get(URL);
    return userData.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return {};
  }
};
```

Todo el código unido se vería así:

```
rt { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "./styles.css";

const URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";

const getData = async () => {
  try {
    const userData = await axios.get(URL);
    console.log(userData);
    return userData.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return {};
  }
};

function getRows(data) {
  return data.map((row) => (
    <tr>
      <td> {row.name || "None"} </td>
      <td> {row.email || "None"} </td>
      <td> {row.phone || "None"} </td>
    </tr>
  ));
}

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});
  useEffect(() => {
    // Indicador para saber si ya obtuvo datos remotos
    let mounted = true;
    getData(1).then((data) => {
      console.log(2);
      if (mounted) {
        setData(data);
      }
    }, []);
    return function cleanup() {
      mounted = false;
    };
  }, []);
  return !data.length ? (
    "Loading..."
  ) : (
    <>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{getRows(data)}</tbody>
      </table>
    </>
  );
}
```

Puede ver el ejemplo funcionando en [éste enlace](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-leakey-dgkhl?file=/src/App.js:0-71).

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. Aun soy algo nuevo en react pero, usar el useEffect sin dependencias haría que solo se ejecutara una vez no? La función `getUserData(user_id)` solo obtiene los datos de 1 usuario, por lo que necesitaría ejecutarla varias veces ya que debo obtener los datos de todos los usuarios conforme se vayan cargando en la tabla.

Comment: Asi es, ese solo era un ejemplo acerca de cómo puedes obtener un dato, sin embargo puedes hacer una función tan compleja como requieres.