# Crear lista dinámica en React

Tags: reactjs

Necesito que el usuario escriba un numero en el input numero y que con el evento onChange cree una lista de inputs de acuerdo con la cantidad del numero que haya sido ingresado.

Si ingreso el num 3, que cree una lista con 3 inputs.
[funcionamiento](https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-fast-tze1d?file=/src/App.js)

```html
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App(props) {
  var listRespuestas = [];

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    for (let i = 1; i <= e.target.value; i++) {
      listRespuestas.push(i);
    }
    console.log(listItems);
  };

  var listItems = listRespuestas.map((number) => (
    <li key={number.toString()}>
      <input type="text" className="mb-1" autoComplete="off" />
    </li>
  ));

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <h6>Cantidad de respuestas</h6>

        <input
          type="text"
          required
          className="mb-2"
          autoComplete="off"
          name="numero"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </div>

      <ol>{listItems}</ol>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se puede intentar lo siguiente, se crea un estado `listRespuestas`:

```
const [listRespuestas, setlistRespuestas] = useState([]);
```

Después, se debe regresar el estado `listRespuestas` a su valor inicial `empty array`, cada que el usuario ingrese el número de `inputs` que se quieren crear; esto se puede lograr usando [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates):

```
setlistRespuestas(prevState => {
      prevState = [];
      for (let i = 1; i <= e.target.value; i++) {
         prevState.push(i);
      }
      let stateCopy = [...prevState];
      return stateCopy;
});
```

Demo:

```js
function App(props) {
  const [listRespuestas, setlistRespuestas] = React.useState([]);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setlistRespuestas(prevState => {
      prevState = [];
      for (let i = 1; i <= e.target.value; i++) {
         prevState.push(i);
      }
      let stateCopy = [...prevState];
      return stateCopy;
});
  };

  var listItems = listRespuestas.map((number) => (
    <li key={number.toString()}>
      <input type="text" className="mb-1" autoComplete="off" />
    </li>
  ));

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <h6>Cantidad de respuestas</h6>

        <input
          type="text"
          required
          className="mb-2"
          autoComplete="off"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </div>

      <ol>{listItems}</ol>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Aquí, una [respuesta detallada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/443227/c%C3%B3mo-modifico-varios-valores-de-un-objeto-en-react/443267#443267) de como funciona **functional updates**.

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.